# Export ARFF from new Azure Machine Learning Studio?

Tags: azure, arff

I'm working in the new Azure Machine Learning Studio, but I do not see a Convert To ARFF module like there was in Azure Machine Learning Classic.  Does anyone know if this feature still exists and how to access it?

Answer (score 0):

Convert to ARFF module is currently only supported in Azure ML Studio (Classic). Thanks.